# how to download file from flask in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am making a small app that downloads videos from youtube. I am using react native for the frontend, and python flask for the backend.
Here is the code on the server that downloads the video to the server and returns it to the client as an attachment

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
import vid_request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<url>")
def download(url):
    path = vid_request.download(url, r"\tempDownloads")
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

// vid_request file

```
import pytube

def download(url, path):
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+url
    youtubeObject = pytube.YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    out_file = youtubeObject.download(output_path=path)

    return out_file
```

This works when I go to the url and enter the youtube link, but when I do it from react native using this

```
await fetch(`http://192.168.0.12:5000/${input}`);
```

It doesn't work and gives an error, is there a better way for sending the file on the server side, or better way of downloading from the client side?

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: when I try console.log on it gives "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Network request failed". I don't really know what it's supposed to print as the server returns a file, but it's not working

Comment: Are you able to call your api thru any external program, like postman or insomnia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `npx expo install expo-file-system`
2. If its bare React Native, you need to additionally follow this steps:
   https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-47/packages/expo-file-system
3. Amend the following

```
import { downloadAsync, documentDirectory} from 'expo-file-system';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const download = async () => {
    console.log("downloading");
    const { uri: localUri } = await downloadAsync('http://192.168.0.12:5000/video.mp4', documentDirectory + 'video.mp4');
    console.log("download complete. File "+localUri);
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
      <Button title="download" onPress={download}></Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Full Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)

Comment: I have done that but I'm having trouble on the server side, do you know what to do for the server side? Whatever I try for example send_from_directory, or send_file everything returns a 404